# Vlookup If Match combination with an array

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2013

I have a datasheet with 3 criteria. Cost Center, Employee Level, and work country. The sheet looks a little something like this

```
                Australia     China      Hong Kong     India
All    L10      10,000       10,001       10,003       10,004
All    L11      9,000         9,001        9,002        9,003
C9620  L10      10,005       10,006       10,007       10,008
C9620  L11      9,005        9,006        9,007         9,008
```

I have 50 countries, 100+ cost centers, and 10 levels for each cost center.

I am moving the data to another format where it is listed in column form. The salary column has my formula and only works for cost center "all" for all the countries. I believe the issue lies in the Cost center.

```
Country     Cost Center    Level    Salary
Australia      All          L10       10,000
Australia      C952         L10       #N/A
Austraila      C845         L10       #N/A
China          All          L10       10,001
China          C952         L10       #N/A
China          C845         L10       #N/A
```

I have used an array formula to get my answer. 
-`Median Salary by Cost Center'!$B$14:$B$1682     = Cost Centers`
-`Logic Board'!$G14                               = Cost Center`
-`Logic Board'!$H14                               = Employee Level`
-`Median Salary by Cost Center'!$C$13:$AR$1698    = All Data`
-`Logic Board'!$E14                               = Country`
-`Median Salary by Cost Center'!$C$13:$AT$13      = Country`

`=VLOOKUP(IF('Median Salary by Cost Center'!$B$14:$B$1682='Logic Board'!$G14,'Logic Board'!$H14,"NA"),'Median Salary by Cost Center'!$C$13:$AR$1698,MATCH('Logic Board'!$E14,'Median Salary by Cost Center'!$C$13:$AT$13,0),FALSE)`

The expected result has the salary column populated all the way down. Currently it only works for cost center "All". All other cost centers come up with an #N/A

Any ideas would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @teylyn that the most efficient way would be using **Power Query** to unpivot the table to get the desired result. Formula-based answer would probably slow down your calculation given that you have a lot of data to transform.

There is another way of using **Pivot Table and Pivot Chart Wizard** to transform the original table into the one you want with some help from **Text to Column** function.

Here is the instruction of how to find **Pivot Table and Pivot Chart Wizard** function in different versions of Excel: [Where are Pivot Table and PivotChart Wizard in Excel 2007, 2010, 2013, 2016, 2019 and 365](https://www.addintools.com/documents/excel/where-pivot-table.html)

Please see the following steps to transform the table:
[image: Answer]

Cheers :)

Comment: Worked like a charm. Very clear and concise directions.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this might be without formulas. With Power Query you can transform the table with a few clicks.

Add column labels to the first two columns, then add the table to the Power Query editor. Select the first two columns, then use the **Unpivot > Other columns** command on the Transform ribbon.  Rename, re-arrange and sort the data and load it into a worksheet.

[image]

If you don't want to use Power Query, you can use this formula. Refer to the screenshot for cell addresses and adjust accordingly. Be aware that this formula should not be used with whole column references, otherwise it will become very slow.

```
=INDEX($C$2:$F$5,MATCH(J2&K2,INDEX($A$2:$A$5&$B$2:$B$5,0),0),MATCH(I2,$C$1:$F$1,0))
```

[image]

Comment: Formula worked great. I'm sure the power query would too. I didn't want to download anything on my work computer. Thanks